# Error 1127 in MySQL udf creation

Tags: mysql, error-handling, user-defined-functions

i am attempting to create a UDF for use in MySQL.  I have compiled the function using gcc and it works properly.  I then moved the .so file into my plugin directory and entered into the MySQL server.  I attempted to create the function using the following code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION mynew_udf RETURNS INT SONAME 'mynew_udf.so';
```

However, instead of creating the function as it should, the server outputs the following error:

> ERROR 1127 (HY000): Can't find symbol
>   'mynew_udf' in library

Does anyone know a solution for this or why this error would occur?  Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

This error means exactly what it says: The `mynew_udf` symbol can't be found in the shared library.

Without your code, I can only guess why this is the case.  Does your source code have  function signatures that look like this?

```
my_bool mynew_udf_init(UDF_INIT *, UDF_ARGS *args, char *message);  
int mynew_udf(UDF_INIT *initid, UDF_ARGS *args, char *is_null, char *error);
```

As noted on line 151 [here](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~mysql/mysql-server/mysql-trunk/view/head:/sql/udf_example.c): "These must be right or mysqld will not find the symbol!"

If you think you have the right symbols, you could also use `nm` to look at the symbols in `mynew_udf.so`:

```
nm mynew_udf.so | grep mynew_udf
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help with this, I was using some copied code from another function and forgot to change the function names with it.

Comment: And if `nm mynew_udf.so | grep mynew_udf` produces the expected result, but MySQL still complains that it cannot find it?

Comment: Nevermind, found my own answer...for some bizarre reason restarting mysql fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

With this syntax work fine:

From start folder:

> gcc -shared -lstdc++ -fPIC -DMYSQL_DYNAMIC_PLUGIN  -I /usr/include/ -I
>   /usr/local/include/ -I /opt/jasperserver-4.5.0-0/mysql/include/ -o 
>   nomefile.so nomefile.cc
>
> cp nomefile.so /PATH/mysql/lib/plugin/

DB connection string

> /PATH/mysql/bin/mysql -uroot -p test
>
> MYSQL> CREATE AGGREGATE FUNCTION example RETURNS REAL SONAME
>   'udf_example.so';